# SQL Query .. a little help with AVG and MEDIAN using DISTINCT and SUM

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, average, median

I have a query to get the total duration of phone usage for various users...

But I need to be able to work out distinct averages for their usage.. the problem being certain users share phones and I can only grab phone info, so the call duration is repeated and this would skew the data..

So I need an average and a distinct (on the pin.Number field)... it would also be useful to do a Median if that is possible..??

This is the current query...

```
SELECT TOP 40 SUM(Duration) AS TotalDuration, c.Caller, oin.Name, oin.Email, pin.Number, oin.PRN 
FROM Calls as c 
INNER JOIN Phones as pin On c.caller = pin.id 
INNER JOIN officers as oin On pin.id = oin.fk_phones 
WHERE Duration <> 0 AND Placed BETWEEN '01/07/2011 00:00:00' AND '20/08/2011 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY c.Caller, oin.Name, pin.Number, oin.Email, oin.PRN 
ORDER BY TotalDuration DESC
```

Many thanks for any pointers

Here's an example of the current data I am after (but I have added the averages below which is what I am after), as you can see some users share the same phone but the number of seconds is shared between them so don't want that to influence the average (I don't want 11113 seconds repeated), so there needs to be a distinct on each phone number..

[image]

Comment: A sample of data and the expected output might be helpful.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or another RDBMS? And what is wrong with the current query?

Comment: MS SQL 2008 and the current query doesn't bring back the averages. The 'results' I posted are just an example of the output I'd like... Thanks

Comment: So, there are fewer phones than their users, and you want to find the average call duration per user by taking SUM(Calls.Duration) and dividing it by COUNT(Officers.ID), but so that shared phones (and the respective calls) didn't duplicate while calculating the sum. Is that right?

Comment: Wouldn't the median be 24442 and the average be alot smaller ?

Comment: Well to clarify officers can share numbers so Chris and Meg have the same phone number 2345. 

But Meg and Chris have made 11113 seconds worth of calls between them (we don't know who has used the most minutes and that doesn't matter)

I guess the example output above is wrong because I am showing both users but I only really need one user for the purpose of the averages... My query above is one I currently use, I just also need to work out averages but can't figure out how to do that because I am also using SUM... I hope this makes sense?

Comment: t-clausen.dk - yes I just typed random numbers in there I guess I should have actually worked out the averages!! Well spotted... it was just an example but I guess I should have been accurate!! :) I've arrowed you just for spotting it ;-)

Comment: And to clarify my question, do you want the average per user or the average per phone? Same question about the median.

Comment: Average per phone and median per phone, thanks.

Comment: Very well, thank you too. One more question, please. Can the Officers table be necessary for calculating the result? I mean, maybe it should be used for filtering (like 'calculate only the calls from the phones used by officers' as opposed to miscellaneous phones not related to officers).

Comment: No they aren't necessary... Andriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use this, I did it with temporary tables

```
declare @calls table (number char(4), duration int)
declare @officers table(number char(4), name varchar(10))

insert @calls values (3321,1)
insert @calls values (3321,1)
insert @calls values (3321,1)
insert @calls values (3321,42309)

insert @calls values (1235,34555)
insert @calls values (2979,31133)
insert @calls values (2324,24442)
insert @calls values (2345,11113)
insert @calls values (3422,9922)
insert @calls values (3214,8333)


insert @officers values(3321, 'Peter')
insert @officers values(1235, 'Stewie')
insert @officers values(2979, 'Lois')
insert @officers values(2324, 'Brian')
insert @officers values(2345, 'Chris')
insert @officers values(2345, 'Peter')
insert @officers values(3422, 'Frank')
insert @officers values(3214, 'John')
insert @officers values(3214, 'Mark')
```

Sql to get median and average

```
;with a as 
(
select sum(duration) total_duration, number from @calls group by number
)
select avg(a.total_duration) avg_duration, c.total_duration median_duration from a
cross join (
select top 1 total_duration from (
select top 50 percent total_duration from a order by total_duration desc) b order by
total_duration) c
group by c.total_duration
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/108612/

Sql To get the Total durations

```
select o.name, c.total_duration, c.number from @officers o join
(select sum(duration) total_duration, number from @calls group by number) c
on o.number = c.number
order by total_duration desc
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/108611/

Comment: Thanks I was able to use this (well a variation)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that implements the following idea:

1. Get [totals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) per phone ([`SUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)`(Duration)`).
2. [Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) the resulting set by the total duration values ([`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)`OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Duration))`).
3. Include one more column for the total number of rows (`COUNT(*)`[`OVER ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)).
4. From the resulting set, get the average ([`AVG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx)`(TotalDuration)`).
5. Get the median as the average between two values whose rankings are

   1) `N div 2 + 1`,

   2) `N div 2 + N mod 2`,

   where `N` is the number of items, `div` is the integer division operator, and `mod` is the modulo operator.

My testing table:

```
DECLARE @Calls TABLE (Caller int, Duration int);
INSERT INTO @Calls (Caller, Duration)
SELECT 3, 123 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  23 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  15 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 943 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 326 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  74 UNION ALL
SELECT 9,  49 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  66 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  56 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 208 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 112 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 521 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 197 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  23 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,  22 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  24 UNION ALL
SELECT 0,  45;
```

The query:

```
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT
    Caller,
    TotalDuration = SUM(Duration),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Duration)),
    N = COUNT(*) OVER ()
  FROM @Calls
  GROUP BY Caller
)
SELECT
  Average = AVG(TotalDuration),
  Median = AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (N / 2 + 1, N / 2 + N % 2) THEN TotalDuration END)
FROM totals
```

The output:

```
Average     Median
----------- -----------
282         123
```

Note: In Transact-SQL, [`/`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx) stands for integer division if both operands are integer. The modulo operator in T-SQL is [`%`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx).